# Why is $E(Y|X)$ is projection of $Y$(so that error is zero) on plane containing all functions of X and passing through origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, statistical-inference, conditional-expectation

> Why is $E(Y|X)$ is projection of $Y$(so that error is zero) on plane containing all functions of X and passing through origin?

I have recently started studying probability and statistics using harvard lectures. In that professor tried to establish relation between expectation and linear algebra. I did not understand how this holds. kindly elaborate

At 19.46 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjBvCiRt8QA&list=PL2SOU6wwxB0uwwH80KTQ6ht66KWxbzTIo&index=27

Comment: You presumably mean $E(Y|X)$, the conditional expectation, which is a random variable, as opposed to $E(Y/X)$, the expectation of the ratio, which is a number?

Comment: You need Hilbert SpaceTheory for this. Linear algebra is not good enough.

Comment: conditional expectation @WoolierThanThou

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sir can you pls explain in layman terms?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I can see that E(XY)=<X,Y> whn X and Y are normalized. E(Y|X) i am not able to visualise. I just know it is average value of Y when X is kept as some constant.

Comment: @NascimentodeCos That's not *really* the definition of a conditional expectation, though. That only works when the joint distribution of $Y$ and $X$ has a particular form. And Kavi's right that the statement is a statement about Hilbert spaces, so if you are not familiar with these, you would need to read about them first.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou pardon my ignorance. Hilbert spaces come under which area of mathematics? I have not studied maths in detail. I am a mechanical engineering student trying to learn prob and statistics using some youtube lectures

Comment: I guess functional analysis. Basically, the answer to your question would be: $E(Y|X)$ is characterised as the a.s. unique $\sigma(X)$-measurable variable $Z$ such that $\mathbb{E}Z f(X)=\mathbb{E} Yf(X)$ for all measurable maps $f$. It's somewhat clear that if $Y$ has second moment then $Z$ can be chosen as the $L^2$-projection (that's what is meant by projection here) onto the $\sigma(X)$-measurable $L^2$ variables. There's not really much to check - you just need to know what $L^2$ is, what the orthogonal projection is, and what a $\sigma$-algebra is.

Comment: In practice, though, you'll be working with models where the distribution of $(X,Y)$ has density, in which case there is another characterisation of $E(Y|X)$ in terms of the joint density function - this perspective just doesn't make it clear at all how a projection fits into anything.